# References in Roslyn .rsp files

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I see in the CSharpInteractive.rsp you can add a reference to a DLL in the GAC using /r:

How do you add references to your own DLLs?

I tried System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom, it didn't fail but didn't work.

I am trying to add a reference to my DLL that has extension methods.

If I try to add the code for the extension method directly in the interactive window I get this error:

error CS1109: Extension methods must be defined in a top level static class; XYZ is a nested class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to specify a full path for the assembly, in the same way as the gac assembly.

Normally you don't need to change the rsp though. You can add references in a regular submission using:

```
#r "path"
```

Disclaimer: I work at Microsoft on the Roslyn team.

Comment: Kevin, are you still there? I know a lot has changed with this since 2015 SP1.  Is there a way to have a rsp or similar load with your project so you don't have to manually keep setting up for each individual solution (without littering up your main rsp file?)

Comment: We don’t currently allow setting your .rsp file based on a project. You can #load a .csx file that contains your #r’s. Also, extension methods should work at the top-level now.

Comment: What does .rsp stand for?