# Is there a way to setup a working directory for "r and "load commands

Tags: c#, roslyn

Quesiton is relative to 
[References in Roslyn .rsp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883967/references-in-roslyn-rsp-files)

Did install the Roslyn, playing with:
C:\Users\name\Documents\Microsoft Codename Roslyn CTP - October 2011\CSharp\WpfSeedRepl
Walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/hh543924.

I'm unable to load current DLL and csx:

```
> #r "wpfseed.exe"
(1,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'wpfseed.exe' could not be found

> #load "setup.csx"
Specified file not found.
Searched in directory:
  C:\Users\name
>
```

On other hand:

```
> Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
C:\Users\name\Documents\Microsoft Codename Roslyn CTP - October 2011\CSharp\WpfSeedRepl
```

Is there any workaround to not to specify the project folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work at Microsoft on the Roslyn team.

There is not currently a way to change the search path from within the Interactive window.  However, we're considering adding a command to do so in the future.  For now, the paths are rooted at your user directory ("C:\Users\name" above), and you can use relative paths from that directory.  Additionally, you can use paths relative to the process current directory with a ".\", and you can change that with `Environment.CurrentDirectory = "<your path>"`.

For example:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\Users\name\Documents\Microsoft Codename Roslyn CTP - October 2011\CSharp\WpfSeedRepl";
#r ".\wpfseed.exe"
#load ".\setup.csx"
```

Hope this helps!