# The #r directive in C# script does not support relative paths

Tags: c#, reference, .net-assembly, roslyn

According to this post:
[Is there a way to setup a working directory for "r and "load commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180086/is-there-a-way-to-setup-a-working-directory-for-r-and-load-commands)

The `#r` directive can be use with relative path, but it's an old post and I failed finding any relevant recent documentation about that specifically (searched whole afternoon yesterday)

I'm able to add the reference of an assembly of mine when I provide the full absolute path, but it does not work with relative path.

The dll is in the current directory of the running script (verified through `Environment.CurrentDirectory` from the running script):

I tried all those forms:

```
#r ".\MyLib.dll"
#r "MyLib.dll"
#r "D:\Absolute\Path\To\MyLib.dll"
```

Only the last one was working.

I'm using Roslyn library retrieved from NuGet:

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting
```

Version 3.1.0

Has the support for relative path been removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From where is the script runner of the script executing?

---

If you are using *`csi.exe` via the command-line*, for example:

```
C:\dir1>csi.exe .\path\to\script\myScript.csx
```

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` will be the current directory of where `csi.exe` was launched (i.e. `c:\dir1`) and not of the script file (i.e. `c:\dir1\path\to\script`).

---

If you are using *Visual Studio C# Interactive window* to `#load` the file then it is `c:\Users\<your user name>` and not the filepath of the script.

---

If you are using a *custom application referencing `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` library* then `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will be the file location of *your custom app* and not of the script.

A way to resolve this is to set `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to be same as the file directory of your script file (which I'd assume your custom app code would know if it's loading the file somehow) before `CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync()` is called.

For example in your custom app you can do the following:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
// ...

            var scriptDirectory = @"c:\dir1\path\to\script"; // <-- or however else you are getting this. will use this later
            var scriptFilename = "myScript.csx";
            var scriptFilepath = Path.Combine(scriptDirectory, scriptFilename);

            var scriptCode = File.ReadAllText(scriptFilepath);

            Environment.CurrentDirectory = scriptDirectory; // <-- set this before running the script below

            var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(scriptCode);
```

---

Unfortunately, after testing for myself even after changing `Environment.CurrentDirectory` as suggested in [Is there a way to setup a working directory for “r and ”load commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8184821/4872) `#r` still does not work when using relative path. If that did once work then yes it looks to be regression since when that answer was originally posted.

Comment: I'm using from C# Code. From our own application that supports customization using .csx file.
I'm using the library from NuGet Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting within that application and runs the script using the library method: CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync()

I did Environment.CurrentDirectory from within the script so in the "scope" of the script, the directory is the correct one from the script stand point. (The same where the dll I want to reference is located).

Comment: @FrancisP Ok. Thanks for clarifying.  Similar to my original answer, sounds like `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is running from the context of your custom application referencing `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` library. Specifically, the file path that your app is located and launching from and not where the script is.  See my updated answer for a possible fix.

Comment: Well. Just tested and confirmed that `#r` with relative path does not work despite changing `Environment.CurrentDirectory` before the script is executed. :(

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem too and after some digging I found the solution for me on github. I can't find the link right now but I will update if i find it again.

According to the answer to the issue on github, relative paths will only work when executing a script file directly. Roslyn no longer uses `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to search for libraries. The problem is that when using `CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync` you're not running a script file, you're evaluating a string so roslyn doesn't even try to resolve any relative paths.

The solution is to provide a path to your file in ScriptOptions:

```
var scriptCode = File.ReadAllText(scriptFilepath);

var opt = ScriptOptions.Default
            .WithFilePath(scriptFilePath);

var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(scriptCode, options: opt);
```

This solved the problem for me and relative paths are now resolved relative to the path of the script file.

**Update:** link to issue on github https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36417